# Best practice security measures for an enterprise Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

What security measures should a Rails enterprise app have?

Examples of few security measures:

Admin area authenticated and IP restricted

No User added CSS, because of some old browsers can run JavaScript in CSS

Should User information in database be encrypted?

Comment: This would be a laundry list of issues that are usually not unique to Rails and they really depend on your applications use and how users interact with it. Can you give us an example application and then we can provide some examples of security?

Comment: Your question is essentially a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750767/web-applications-development-security-practices-for-application-design Rails is just another way to built a web-app, it faces the same core set of security issues that all online applications do. Unless you're asking "what issues, specific to Rails, should one consider with web apps?", in which case, I would recommend rephrasing your question a bit.

Comment: Examples for security measures for a community which stores user sensitive data

Comment: @Rails beginner you realize that you just described almost every website ever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest looking over the [Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) which should go over the common pitfalls that you would usually encounter. Also check out the additional resources that they list on the guide:

> The security landscape shifts and it is important to keep up to date,
>   because missing a new vulnerability can be catastrophic. You can find
>   additional resources about (Rails) security here:
>
> - The Ruby on Rails security project posts security news regularly:
>     http://www.rorsecurity.info
> - Subscribe to the Rails security [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-security)
> - [Keep up to date on the other application layers](http://secunia.com/) (they have a weekly
>     newsletter, too)
> - A [good security blog](http://ha.ckers.org/blog/) including the [Cross-Site scripting Cheat Sheet](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html)

Comment: Should I encrypt user data in database? And keep logs of login attempts?

Comment: You should follow that guide and don't bother rolling your own authentication if this if for a serious project, use something that has community support like Devise. And you already have logs of the login attempts in the default Rails logs.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of essential security precautions such as a strong authentication system, validating user input to mitigate XSS and SQL injection attacks and escaping HTML at the views.

You can find information about common Ruby on Rails application vulnerabilities and their countermeasures at the [Zen Rails Security Checklist](https://github.com/brunofacca/zen-rails-security-checklist).